# Message: Unterminated string constant

Tags: javascript, html

I am receiving the following error message in Internet Explorer:

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Wed, 30 May 2012 16:59:09 UTC
>
> Message: Unterminated string constant Line: 201 Char: 744 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://new.crystalcoach.com/

The browser is displaying "Page loaded, but with errors." I'm not sure what's causing the error... It all seems to be right? The error seems to be on Line 201. Can someone find the error & explain how to fix it?

Comment: Use appropriate tags. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a long Javascript on lines 201 and 202 ("Add-On Code: Rounded Items") and it appears that it is supposed to be in one line, not two. The line break interrupted the code and a string (".qmmc) got interrupted (no closing quote).

Comment: Where's the closing quote supposed to be after the ".qmmc?

Comment: @StevenThompson If you figured it out, it would be helpful to share the details. https://xkcd.com/979/